# How do I get my code to check for valid username and password combination?

Tags: php

I am making a website, and I only want certain users to be able to view it for now. So I though about setting up a user/pass validation, and setup some variables containing the usernames and passwords which are allowed, yet there seems to be an error because even if I put a random username or pass, you can still view the site. This is my code:

login.php

```
<body>
<form action="check.php" method="get">
<Username:<input type="text" name="user" maxlength='8'>
<Password:<input type="password" name="password" maxlength='12'>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
print "<br><code> To proceed to the main page, please give the information and then click the button. You will be automatically be redirected.<br> </code>";
?>
</body>
```

check.php (checks the info)

```
<?php

$user1 = '';
$user2 = '';
$pass1 = '';
$pass2 = '';

$_GET['user'];
$_GET['password'];

if($_GET['user'] && ($_GET['password'] = $user1 && $user2 && $pass1 && $pass2)) {
    header( "refresh:1;url=" );
    
} else {
echo 'You are unable to view this page yet, please try again later.';    
}{
}
?>
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong? I've been trying for quite a while now but no success.

#### EDIT

I've sorted changing some of my code, not sure who actually helped me.

Comment: ***Never*** store passwords in plain text.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, Yeah, I will md5 that once I get this working.

Comment: You need to use something stronger than `md5`.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, I will figure something out, will make it all database driven after it's all working properly anyway, it's just for the time being.

Comment: If you simply want to lock access to a website you can define login and passwords using the file .htaccess
http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Comment: All your code does is check the values are logically truce - not that they match anything

Comment: @Virus721, I'm not sure how to do that, and this way (it may sound weird) but I get to use php and improve my skills.

Comment: @Script47 Assuming you want for user1 nicknamed "Script47" to have a password "test", you'd have to do something like: `$user1='Script47'; $pas1='test';` But that also requires to fix the `if` statement. Not sure why my answer is downvoted, but it should do what you ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `POST` for passing passwords.

Here's a more secure way of storing passwords.

**The Form**

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" maxlength='8'>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength='12'>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**The Post** `(check.php)`

```
$siteKey = 'YPfiC+NIY2JKXbRK_riP!nd0_7AC~9X s`%ax+|*3UpxlZAll3(E?eW#w-1`)|X ';

$users = array(
    array('user' => 'bob', 
          'password' => '56cee8ccfa519021a945a75c01c73c9538c9bce4e96842392d65e81161f8b1c9',
          'salt' => '> c>>.Sr>J-MPn@d/'),
    array('user' => 'tom', 
          'password' => 'd275d8f08ada53d42394b3f13b57f1ef8dad7405d563801d35bccc60038fd14a',
          'salt' => '=]:iK/VMb-{wYg`6+'));

if( !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ) {
    foreach($users as $sub) {
        if( $sub[user] == $_POST['user'] ) {
           $hashPostPoassword = hash('sha256', $siteKey . $sub[salt] . $_POST['user']);

           if( $hashPostPassword == $sub[password] ) {
               //verified
           }
           else {
               echo "Wrong password";
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things about this make me worry. 1st why is your form a GET and not POST.

Also why is this not database driven.

Assuming you do database:
If you store your username and password as plain text just run a query with whatever the user inputs and see if a result is returned.

```
  Select * from users_table where username = $_POST['user'] and password = $_POST['password'];

 if(result from query) {
      //then the user exists and the info entered is correct
 } else {
    //either username and password is wrong or no such user exists.
 }
```

otherwise you only have one = sign and need == instead

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you are using a single equal sign which will just assign the value on the right to the variable on the left. If you want to do a comparison, you need to use two equal signs:
if($user == $_GET['user'])

Answer (score -1):

You should really take a look at your syntax. What's that supposed to mean?

- `$_GET['password'] = $user1` *will* always be true. [Notice you are missing one `=`]
- `&&user2` will always be *false*.

Not sure what you want, actually. Maybe this?

`if(($_GET['password'] == $pass1 && $_GET['user'] == $user1) || ($_GET['password'] == $pass2 && $_GET['user'] == $user2))`

Answer (score -1):

If you want your users to be hard coded for a temporary solution, you can do :

```
<?php

$users = [
    'user0' => 'password0',
    'user1' => 'password1',
    'user2' => 'password2',
    'user3' => 'password3'
];

$login    = isset($_REQUEST['login'   ]) ? $_REQUEST['login'   ] : null;
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? $_REQUEST['password'] : null;

if( ! is_null($login) && in_array($login, $users) && $password === $users[$login]) {
    // Show your web site
}

?>
```

Note that this is only a db-free solution that you should only you, as you said, "for now".