# how to save userid enter by user during login and use it to get relevent data about user using this id

Tags: php

i haven't have much knowledge about php. so please try to be simple and easy.
i am making an employee management system. i have made two tables.

"login" table have id and password.

"employee data" table have id,name,age,sex,salary.

when user loged in he has three option.
veiw profile
edit profile
logout.

what i tried to do is to store the id of user entered by him/her during login. and use it to get his profile information from "employee data" table using that id. how i can do this with???

THNX everybody for ur help. i got my answer. it could b done with sessions. i should have to search for it before. Anyhow i want se thank to all 4 their attention and useful suggestion. i got much from your answers.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, please?

Comment: Hm, this is very common question. Did you read FAQ section?

Comment: could you please send the link. i havn't read FAQ section. bksi

Comment: Did you give at leas a try to search for this in google before post? here is one duplicate for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957388/how-do-i-get-my-code-to-check-for-valid-username-and-password-combination

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this would help you or not but i doing the same thing relate with your question.
my method
in the profile.php should have

```
$id=$_SESSION['employee_id'];
```

then in the login

```
$_SESSION['employee_id'] = $db_employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather from your question it sounds like to want to keep the `id` from a successful login and use that data to access that person's data from the `employee` table.

In that case I would suggest you use php sessions http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php.

After validating a successful login you could then do something like so in your login script.

```
// Start the session
session_start();
// Store ID
$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
```

Then in any further pages you wish to grab the session data you need to restart the session and then you can reference the data. So in your employee data script.

```
// Start the session
session_start();
// Logged in id
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Hope this has helped, if it has not please be more specific to what it is you actually want/need to do!

Answer (score 0):

After validating the user and storing the the id in a session variable, you are displaying 3 options to the user.

Option 1. --view profile-- (If the user selects this option)

Step1.1: Connect to the database, query user based on the ID and store the information retrived info in a variable, and display the variable as u want it.

```
$conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM tablename where id = $id";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);  // executes sql
$empDtls=odbc_fetch_row($rs); // returns the row result from db
print_r($empDtls); //prints the array
```

the second part of the question is very similar to the first one, hope u can figure it out

For the third part use the below to log out

```
session_destroy(); header("Location: index.php");
```